# SwiftにおいてUITextFieldの配列を作る方法

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Swiftによるプログラミング初心者です。
UITextFieldをUIStepperなどの値に応じて増やしたり減らしたりしたいと考えています。
そこで、足がかりとして以下のような関数を作りました。

```
func makeUITextField(frame: CGRect, DataNum: Int) -> [UITextField] {
    var textFields = [UITextField]()
    for var i = 0; i < DataNum; i++ {
        textFields[i].frame = frame
        textFields[i].borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
        textFields[i].keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
        textFields[i].returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
        textFields[i].delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(textFields[i])

    }

    return textFields

}
```

コンパイルは通るのですが、各配列を定義するときにエラーが起きてしまします。

どのようにすれば、うまくtextfieldを複数作れるか教えて下さい。
どうぞ宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のような形でいかがでしょうか？

```
func makeUITextField(frame: CGRect, DataNum: Int) -> [UITextField] {
　　var textFields:[UITextField] = []
   for var i = 0; i < DataNum; i++ {
   　　let textField:UITextField = UITextField.init(frame: frame)
       textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
       textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
       textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
       textField.delegate = self
       textFields.append(textField)
       self.view.addSubview(textField)     
   }

   return textFields

}
```

1個ずつ要素を作ってから配列に追加すれば良いと思います。

Comment: `UITextField.init(frame: frame)`は、`UITextField(frame: frame)`ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます〜！
無事解決しました。

細かいことのようで、順序が大切なのですね。
勉強になりました！